JTE Spring Boot are there prebuild templates to use?
does anyone has used JTE with Spring Boot? Is it possible to to use templates from here to build webpages? https://wrapbootstrap.com

JTE is a templating engine so IT SHOULD AND IT IS POSSIBLE THAT you can do this...just make sure the static files (.css and .js) are in the resources/static folder of your Spring boot project and all is well. You reference them from your .jte files (just the html files from the referenced template website [https://wrapbootstrap.com]) but renamed and kept under the src/main/jte directory.
So example assume that am given a template (.html file, .css file, .js file), and named ( home.html. styles.css, actions.js )

I copy home.html to src/main/jte

I rename it to home.jte
3.I copy styles.css and actions.js to /resources/static

I change the path of these files in my home.jte ( was given as a .html).So it look like this href="/styles.css" and for js src="/actions.js"
5.Then my simple controller will be like
 @GetMapping("/")
 public String homeView(){
 // doesnt matter do anything its your world
  return "home";

}


I use tailwindcss with it and its a superb templating engine for Java like I have stared the doc for a time less than I spent staring at any other doc. And everything about it feels made-for-a-java-dev all the way down!!!.
Boostrap a JTE Springboot up from this link [https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.4.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=21&groupId=com.ex&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=JTE%20%2B%20Springboot%20demo&packageName=com.ex.demo&dependencies=web,jte]

Thank you that worked but is not really fun :) Using vaadin now
